Store gets called even if set to the same value more than once
i am using vue3 with options api
for the storeTest.vue posted below, every time i set a value to it, the respective wachter gets executed, but it also gets excuted even if the i set the same object twice!!
according to my understanding, the wachter in code section watch posted below should be executed if only the store is set to different value of the object.
please let me know why the code in section watch posted below gets executed even if i set the same value to the StoreTest twice?
code:
StoreTest.setters.set({
    geojson: this.#featureRecentlyRequestedProcessing.value.get(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOJSON.description),
    order: this.#featureRecentlyRequestedProcessing.value.get(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOM_ORDER.description),
});

storeTest.vue:
<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
  }

export const StoreTest = ({
  state: reactive({
    array: [],
  }),
  getters: {
    get() {
      return StoreTest.state.array;
    },
  },
  setters: {
    set(obj) {
        StoreTest.state.array.push(obj);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    initialize() {
        StoreTest.state.array = [];
    },
  }
});
</script>

watch:
created() {
    console.log(verboseTag, 'created()');

    this.$watch(this.refStoreTest.getters.get, (newVal, oldVal) => {
        msg = JSON.stringify({msg: verboseTag + '@watch refStoreTest.getters.get()', newVal: newVal, oldVal: oldVal});
        console.log(msg);
        newVal = newVal.sort((a,b) => a.order-b.order);
        this.refStroeRecentlyHoveredGeometriesProps.setters.set(newVal); 
    }, { deep: true });
}


Can you clarify which value you talk about? Is it .set({ geojson:  ... }) ? You're not setting it, despite the method is called "set", you're pushing a new element to the array. And it's new object every time. It's unknown what geojson, etc equal to, but if you want to avoid pushing the same data, do a check somewhere

@EstusFlask thanks for your attention.in my code, i push the same object which is consisting of order, geojson keies more than once, and i want to watcher to NOT allow pushing the same object, imean, i want if the same object is already pushed, then for any subsequent push operation to the same object, the watcher should not be called..is that possible please?

Do you need to not avoid pushing, just avoid watching it?

@EstusFlask i want, when it is pushed for the second time, then the watcher do not get executed

Sorry, I don't understand, is "array" allowed to contain duplicate objects?

@EstusFlask no, it should not be allowed to have duplicates

Then as said, you need to do a check somewhere, likely if ... in set method. You can probably avoid this by using Map or Set instead of an array, but it's hard to tell because it's unknown what your data looks like

@EstusFlask i thought it is an internal mechanisim of the watcher not to be called when the same value inserted successively more than once

The problem is newVal === oldVal because you mutated the object, there's no way to tell what caused it. There may be ways but they are for debugging only. This would require to change the way you store data to track changes. But since you aren't supposed to allow dupes in the first place, this is the problem that needs to be solved

@EstusFlask would you please answer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78477713/how-to-introduce-v-model-for-a-drop-down-list
